# Unable to register extension > com.exxeta.iss.sonar.esql.core.EsqlSourceImporter

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I am using sonar-scanner 3.0 for linux with Sonarqube 5.6 and runner 2.4. When I go to initiate a scan I get the following

> WARN: SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to
>   support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of
>   your project.

And also the following error

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to register extension
>   com.exxeta.iss.sonar.esql.core.EsqlSourceImporter

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

update: I have installed the latest scanner (3.3) and errors remain the same.

Many thanks

Adam

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me, that your version of the Esql plugin is not compatible with your SonarQube version. The latest version should have no problems with SonarQube 5.6.

But if you only want to analyze COBOL, the ESQL-plugin wouldn't help you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can find is simply disabling the Esql plugin by uninstalling it via Sonar web interface. 
 I don't know if this will have any impact on COBOL scans, but the scanner at least executes cleanly now.

Answer (score 0):

Your self-answer indicates that you're analyzing COBOL files.

For most languages, prior to analyzing a project, you start by checking it out of SCM, thus leaving SCM tracking files in the project directory. From those tracking files, the analysis can easily determine the flavor and location of the SCM, and interrogate it for further details on each file.

Since you're analyzing COBOL, you probably can't check the "project" out directly, and instead had a batch process dump all the files in your analysis directory. Those warnings (which are just that - harmless warnings) are just telling you that analysis can't figure out what/where your SCM is and so it won't incorporate "blame" data. You can squash the warnings by going to **Administration > General Settings > SCM** and toggling **Disable the SCM Sensor** at either the project or global level.

Regarding the `EsqlSourceImporter` error, uninstalling the plugin was the best thing to do. You probably want to follow up with the author(s) of that plugin, reporting both plugin version and SonarQube version.